# Page-break breaks the side borders on the page

Tags: border, wkhtmltopdf, page-break

I have a long page with left and right side borders. And the content is forms with different sections, inside those, I have made page-break as avoid.
Problem is, when the page is breaking, the side borders are also breaking. Means, there are no borders at the end of a page if there is any page break.

Thanks,
-Sovan

Comment: I think that's simply a wkhtmltopdf feature.

Comment: @Nenotlep can u please post the answer.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have a solution. I meant that wkhtmltopdf works just like Sovan said; the borders break where the page breaks and that this is by design so there is no supported way around this issue. Sorry to be unclear!

Comment: Yes and that looks weird in the page, that's why I was looking for any support or any workaround on this. Experts, if you have any idea please share.